# Two networks of type C on one interface

Tags: networking, gateway

i need some help configuring routes.

This is the situation:

I have one ISP who is providing me with two /27 networks.

ISP_NET1 -> 40.40.40.32/27 (ISP GATEWAY 40.40.40.33)

ISP_NET2 -> 40.40.50.32/27 (ISP GATEWAY 40.40.50.33)

On my gateway (Ubuntu machine) i have one NIC which is connected to the ISP. It is configured to use 40.40.40.34 with default gateway 40.40.40.33 .

Second gateway NIC is connected to a Layer 2 switch on to which there are multiple other servers connected. Each server has one public IP out of ISP_NET1 or a small range like /29.

Right now servers on the L2 switch using ISP_NET1 works as expected. However i am not sure how i should configure ISP_NET2 on gateway so that "clients" having an address of ISP_NET2 will go though it's origin gateway (40.40.50.33).

I hope my description is understandable.

Comment: Can you share your ideas on how to solve it, or what you have tried?

Comment: A schematic including all interfaces of all equipments with IP addresses on them if relevant would help. I have trouble understanding what's the gateway's role, since it's a gateway. Providing a direct route between the two /27 avoiding traffic to go through the ISP for this case? Or is it routing something else?